# Is it possible to launch .fxml (dialog) with IntelliJ plugin?

Tags: plugins, intellij-idea, dialog, fxml

Is it possible to launch .fxml (javafx resource file) with IntelliJ plugin ?

if someone can share any sample , I will appreciate
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

public class NewTestDlg  {

```
final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();
Stage stage;

public void ShowDialog() {

    Platform.setImplicitExit(false);

    // create JavaFX scene
    PlatformImpl.startup(() -> {
        Parent root;
        try {
            stage = new Stage();
            stage.setTitle("New Test");
            BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
            FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("NewTestDlg.fxml"));
            loader.setClassLoader(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
            root = (Parent) loader.load();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 610, 345);
            fxPanel.setScene(scene);
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());
            System.err.println("Exception in ShowDialog");
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    });

}
```

}